# Java Speech API tutorials?

Tags: java, speech-recognition, sphinx4, jsapi

I'm looking to play around with the JSAPI, but I can't find any tutorials on how to do it. I know Sphinx 4 uses JSAPI and there are a few (pretty bad) tutorials for that. From preliminary research and playing around with Sphinx, it's a lot more than I need. I'm simply trying retrieve a spoken sentence and convert it to text. From there, I'll manipulate the string how I need to. Is this within the realm of JSAPI or do I need to use Sphinx? Anyone know of any good tutorials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there are no free fully implemented standalone JSAPI compliant speech recognizer. I am afraid you will have to use Sphinx.

Moreover, "retrieve a sentence" is not a simple task at all. There is actually a lot to do before you even start recognizing the sentence. Look at the guides for sphinx:

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/doc/ProgrammersGuide.html